# How to catch duplicate entries in text file in linux

Tags: linux, grep

Text file:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
1 1
```

I want to catch `1 1` as duplicated

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear, but you can **filter out duplicate lines** with `uniq`:

```
sort file.txt | uniq
```

or simply

```
sort -u file.txt
```

(thanks RobEarl)

You can also **print only repeating lines** with

```
sort file.txt | uniq -d
```

Comment: `sort -u file.txt` would also filter out duplicates

Comment: actually that works for me
`sort file.txt | uniq -d`
Thank, Lev

Comment: I will keep in mind thank you, Lev.

Answer (score 5):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'array[$0]++' file.txt
```

Results:

```
1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it easily:

```
sort -u file.txt
```

OR

```
awk '!x[$0]++' file.txt
```